# How to prevent <options> from displaying while exporting a javascript DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the DataTables jQuery libary to create tables, and want to enable exporting of them using its button functionality.  I have it working, except when it does the export it includes all of the  in the  filter of the header as part of the header.

The code I'm using to generate the select filter for searching is:

```
this.api().columns([2, 3]).every( function () {
  var column = this;
  var select = $('<br/><select><option value=""></option></select>')
    .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
    .on( 'change', function () {
      var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
      $(this).val()
    );
    column
      .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
      .draw();
  } );

  column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
  select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
} );
```

} );

I'm turning on the buttons by using:

```
dom: 'Bfrtip', 
buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ] }
```

And when I go to export the results get for the column heading are:

**Created ByA. FadhelA. GarciaC. FullerD. HauserJ. Perdomo**

The HTML after DataTables load is:

```
<th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_iMZk6N3q3je7" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Created By: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 137px;">
  Created By
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A. Fadhel">A. Fadhel</option>
    <option value="A. Garcia">A. Garcia</option>
    <option value="C. Fuller">C. Fuller</option>
    <option value="D. Hauser">D. Hauser</option>
    <option value="J. Perdomo">J. Perdomo</option>
  </select>
</th>
```

How can I get it to export without showing the options in the select?

Thanks!

Comment: Try declaring the column names on your Datatables config.

Answer (score 0):

You made the `<select>` filter part of the header when you appended it to the header with `.appendTo( $(column.header()) )`. Since you are exporting a table (I assume like this example [DataTables Example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html)
) you are exporting everything inside it including the `<select>`. Do you need to have the filter inside the table?

**If not:** Put the `<select>` element somewhere else, like inside a `<div>`.

**If so:** Try removing the `select` element before export and re-appending it afterward.
Use `select.detach();` before the export and `select.appendTo( $(column.header()) );` after exporting. By using `.detach()` the onchange function should stay intact.

If you could clarify why you put the filter inside that would be helpful.

Comment: To make the UI more friendly, I think the select needs to be in the column header, as each column has it's own search box or select box to use The table is not fixed, so I don't know how I would get the search boxes to be positioned properly above the columns if I put them into their own DIVs.

I can try to remove the SELECT, but I'm not great with javaScript, so I'll have to dig into how the buttons work to figure that out.   Thanks.

Comment: Good luck! If you could post whatever code guides the actual exporting, I might be able to help further if you run into more trouble.